# How to support one to many relationships with Azure Mobile Services Android

Tags: android, one-to-many, azure-mobile-services

I just recently starting using Azure Mobile Services. I am in the process of setting up my database. However I am not sure how I am going to handle one to many/many to many relationships. Azure Mobile has not out of the box support for this so I am not sure what else to do. One approach would be to just store the foreign key id in a particular entity and then run a query on that table to get all items that match a particular id. I think that might be a bit too time consuming. Not sure. Any suggestions or insights on how this can be done. 
Would I have to resort to creating some form of logic on the backend with JavaScript to create the actual relationships on the server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to support one to many relationships using the AMS for Android is to create an ArrayList and store the foreign keys/ids inside the the particular table. That ArrayList then contains the ids of the relevant entities that you want to retrieve so all you would have to do is retrieve the array and extract the ids. AWS does not support serialization and deserialization for ArrayList at the moment therefore would you have to write a custom serializer to achieve this. This can be done by using GSON. Here is an example.

```
public class CollectionSerializer<E> implements JsonSerializer<Collection<E>>,
    JsonDeserializer<Collection<E>> {

public JsonElement serialize(Collection<E> collection, Type type,
                             JsonSerializationContext context) {
    JsonArray result = new JsonArray();
    for(E item : collection){
        result.add(context.serialize(item));

    }

    return new JsonPrimitive(result.toString());
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Collection deserialize(JsonElement element, Type type,
                              JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    JsonArray items = (JsonArray) new JsonParser().parse(element.getAsString());
    ParameterizedType deserializationCollection = ((ParameterizedType) type);
    Type collectionItemType = deserializationCollection.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    Collection list = null;

    try {
        list = (Collection)((Class<?>) deserializationCollection.getRawType()).newInstance();
        for(JsonElement e : items){
            list.add((E)context.deserialize(e, collectionItemType));
        }
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        throw new JsonParseException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new JsonParseException(e);
    }

    return list;
}
}
```

After this is complete you then add it to the MobileServiceClient instance you created.

```
 mClient.registerSerializer(ArrayList.class,new CollectionSerializer<Object>());
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to what Joel mentioned is that you can have "regular" relationships on the client side, and then denormalize them - not only the keys, but the whole values - prior to inserting them on the server. The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/08/29/complex-types-and-azure-mobile-services-android-version.aspx shows some ways where this can be done.

Comment: Thanks alot for this solution. I am going to use this instead :)